# Durga Devi's Weapon that killed Mahishasura?

Tags: asuras, weapon, durga

The Legend of Durga , slaying the demon Mahisha talks about that the gods combined their energies (shakti) into the female form of Durga, a fierce manifestation of the Goddess (Devi). She received all the weapons of the gods, symbolic of their individual powers, but stronger when wielded together.

But what is the name of the stick/club that is generally represented in various pictures that used to do it and who gave it to Her?

Comment: It’s called a musala.